# Intrinsic benefit of using a LinkedList class to point to head Node vs. just using Node*

Tags: c++, linked-list, design-principles

We can define a `LinkedListNode` as below:

```
template <typename T>
struct LinkedListNode {
    T val;
    LinkedListNode* next;
    LinkedListNode() : val{}, next(nullptr) {}
    LinkedListNode(T x) : val{ x }, next(nullptr) {}
    LinkedListNode(T x, LinkedListNode* next) : val{ x }, next(next) {}
};
```

If we want to define a function that takes a "Linked List", we have two options. First, we could pass a `LinkedListNode*` to the function.

```
template <typename T>
int func(LinkedListNode<T>* node);
```

Second, we could define a `LinkedList` class that holds a pointer to the "head" node. Then we could define a function that takes a `LinkedList`.

```
template <typename T>
struct LinkedList {
    LinkedListNode<T>* head;
    // other member functions
};

template <typename T>
int func(LinkedList<T>& llist);
```

One reason the second appears preferable because it *might* allow better encapsulation of functions that modify a "Linked List". For example, a `FindMax` that takes a `LinkedListNode*` might better fit as a member function of `LinkedList` than as a member function of `LinkedListNode`.

**What concrete reasons are there to prefer one over the other?** I'm especially interested in reasons you might prefer to just use `LinkedListNode*`s.

Comment: Both methods can work. Which one works best for your situation?

Comment: @tadman I don't have a situation. I'm trying to become a better programmer, so I am thinking about how to design a "Linked List". I have a choice here, and I can't give myself concrete reasons to choose one over the other.

Comment: If `LinkedList` is made of nothing but the `head` pointer, than it is entirely equivalent (aside from naming) to a pointer to a `LinkedListNode`. But `LinkedList` would allow other options if the layout is not set in stone. For example, it could store a `size` so that the length of the list can be computed in O(1) time instead of O(n). This is the sort of benefits that can be achieved by encapsulation. Also proper object lifetime becomes a lot easier.

Comment: Best way to learn: Try both and see how it works out. We can talk all day about this and it won't make any sense. If you try it you'll know how it *feels* and, more importantly, what feels best for you. Questions like this are often too subjective to answer. It's like asking "I want to try ice cream. What's the best flavour?"

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde storing a "size" is a perfect answer to this question. Thank you.

Comment: "Encapsulation" is a hazy concept at best, and although there are rigid definitions in some schools of thinking, there are many competing schools with many definitions. If you want to know how C++ approaches it by default, look at the Standard Library containers that implement linked lists to see what technique is used there.

Comment: @mana The second scenario would require the list to forward node functionality to the head node. How that overhead (extra layer) weighs against the advantages (encapsulation) depends on the purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining an actual `LinkedList` type allows you to directly support operations that would be relatively difficult to support by just passing around a pointer to a node.

One comment has already mentioned storing the size of the linked list as a member, so you can have a function return the size of the linked list in constant time. That is a useful thing to do, but I think it only hints at the real point, which (in my opinion) is having things that apply to the linked list as a whole, rather than just operations on individual nodes.

In C++, one obvious possibility here is having a destructor that properly destroys a complete linked list when it goes out of scope.

```cpp
int foo() { 
    LinkedList a;
    // code that uses `a`

} // <-- here `a` goes out of scope, and should be destroyed
```

One of the big features of C++ as a whole is deterministic destruction, and its support for that is based on destructors that run when objects go out of scope.

With a linked list, you'd (at least normally) plan on all the nodes in the linked list being allocated dynamically. If you just use a pointer to node, it'll be up to you to keep track of when you no longer need/want a particular linked list, and manually destroy all the nodes in the linked list when it's no longer needed.

By creating a linked-list class, you get the benefit of deterministic destruction, so you no longer need to keep track of when a list is no longer needed--the compiler tracks that for you, and when it goes out of scope, it gets destroyed automatically.

I'd also expect a linked list to support copy construction, move construction, copy assignment, and move assignment--and probably also a few things like comparison (at least for in/equality, and possibly ordering). And all of these require a fair amount of manual intervention if you decide to implement your linked list as a pointer to a node, instead of having an actual linked list class.

As such, I'd say if you really want to use C++ (even close to how it's intended to work) creating a class to encapsulate your linked list is an absolute necessity. As long as you're just passing around pointers to nodes, what you're writing is fundamentally C (even if it may use some features specific to C++ so a C compiler won't accept it).

Answer (score 3):

I think before you even choose to use a singly linked list, you should have some reason to use it over plain `std::vector`. You need actual benchmarks that show that a singly linked list would improve performance in the particular application you have in mind; you'd be surprised how often it makes things worse, not better. Hint: theoretic computational complexity is orthogonal from memory access patterns, and on modern CPUs the memory access patterns determine performance - most computation is essentially free, in that it takes no extra time: it gets hidden under all the cache misses.

Then you should have a reason not to use `std::forward_list`. But maybe you need intrusive linked lists: then make a case for not using `boost::intrusive::slist<T>` or a similar existing and well tested library type.

If you're still going forward with your own implementation, then the very first step would be to use `std::unique_ptr` as the owning pointer for child nodes, instead of manual memory management - that way it'll be very easy to show that no memory is being leaked - the code becomes correct by construction and memory leaks require extra effort vs. happening by omission.

In other words: don't reinvent the wheel unless you have a well articulated reason for that. Of course, you can implement linked lists all you want as an exercise, but be aware that you're most likely implementing a container that you'll make the least use of - so I'd argue that you'd learn a lot more about how C++ works by implementing e.g. a vector/array container.

If you do use `std::unique_ptr`, or even manual memory management, you're likely to run into the destructor stack explosion pitfall. Consider

```
template <typename T>
struct LinkedListNode1 {
    T val;
    std::unique_ptr<LinkedListNode1> next;
};

template <typename T>
struct LinkedListNode2 {
    T val;
    LinkedListNode2* next = nullptr;
    ~LinkedListNode2() { delete next; }
};
```

In both cases, the destructor gets invoked recursively, and if the list is sufficiently long, you'll run out of stack. Recursion is also usually less efficient than a loop. To prevent that, you must be never deallocating nodes that have non-null `next`.

```
template <typename T>
struct LinkedListNode1 {
    T val;
    std::unique_ptr<LinkedListNode1> next;
    ~LinkedListNode1() {
      auto node = std::move(next);
      while (node)
        node = std::move(node->next);
      assert(!next);
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct LinkedListNode2 {
    T val;
    LinkedListNode2* next = {};
    ~LinkedListNode2() {
      using std::swap;
      LinkedListNode2* node = {};
      swap(node, next);
      while (node) {
        LinkedListNode2* tmp = {};
        swap(tmp, node);
        assert(!node);
        swap(node, tmp->next);
        assert(!tmp->next);
        delete tmp;
      }
      assert(!next);
    }
};
```

Smart pointers make the code much simpler. I wrote the raw pointer version with swaps to make it easier to show that no memory is leaking: a swap used correctly never "loses" a value.

> For example, a `FindMax` that takes a `LinkedListNode*`

That's again reinventing the wheel. In C++, the idiom for "finding a maximum element" is [`std::max_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) from `#include <algorithm>`. You should leverage the algorithms that the standard library provides (and any others you may need, e.g. from Boost or header-only libraries).

To do that, you need an iterator for the list. It will be, by necessity, a [*LegacyForwardIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator). Here, *is a* has a strict technical meaning: it's a concise way of saying "your iterator will fulfill the concept of and abide by the contract of *LegacyForwardIterator*".

Such an iterator would look very roughly as follows:

```
template <typename T>
class LinkedListNode1 {
    std::unique_ptr<LinkedListNode1> next;

    template <typename V> class iterator_impl {
        LinkedListNode1 *node = {};
        using const_value_type = std::add_const_t<V>;
        using non_const_value_type = std::remove_const_t<V>;
    public:
        using value_type = V;
        using reference = V&;
        using pointer = V*;

        iterator_impl() = default;
        template <typename VO>
        iterator_impl(const iterator_impl<VO> &o) : node(o.operator->()) {}
        explicit iterator_impl(LinkedListNode1 *node) : node(node) {}

        auto *operator->() const { return node; }
        pointer operator&() const { return &(node->val); }
        reference operator*() const { return node->val; }
        iterator_impl &operator++() { node = node->next.get(); return *this; }
        iterator_impl operator++(int) {
            auto retval = *this;
            this->operator++();
            return retval;
        }
        bool operator==(const iterator_impl &o) const { return node == o.node; }
        bool operator!=(const iterator_impl &o) const { return node != o.node; }
    };
public:
    T val;
    using iterator = iterator_impl<T>;
    using const_iterator = iterator_impl<const T>;
```

The `next` pointer can be made private. Then, the basic functionality would include:

```
    LinkedListNode1() = default;
    LinkedListNode1(const T &val) : val(val) {}
    ~LinkedListNode1() {
      auto node = std::move(next);
      while (node)
        node = std::move(node->next);
    }

    iterator begin() { return iterator(this); }
    iterator end() { return {}; }
    const_iterator begin() const { return const_iterator(this); }
    const_iterator end() const { return {}; }
    const_iterator cbegin() const { return const_iterator(this); }
    const_iterator cend() const { return {}; }

    iterator insert_after(const_iterator pos, const T& value) {
        auto next = std::make_unique<LinkedListNode1>();
        next->val = value;
        auto retval = iterator(next.get());
        pos->next = std::move(next);
        return retval;
    }
```

One would use `insert_after` to extend the list. Other such methods would need to be added, of course.

Then, we'd probably also want to support initializer lists:

```
    LinkedListNode1(std::initializer_list<T> init) {
        auto src = init.begin();
        if (src == init.end()) return;
        val = *src++;
        for (auto dst = iterator(this); src != init.end(); ++src)
            dst = insert_after(dst, *src);
    }
};
```

Now you can pre-populate the list with an initializer list, iterate it using range-for, and use it with standard algorithms:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    LinkedListNode1<int> list{1, 3, 2};
    for (auto const &val : list)
        std::cout << val << '\n';
    assert(*std::max_element(list.begin(), list.end()) == 3);
}
```

But now we come to the most important question:

> What concrete reasons are there to prefer one over the other

The default - the starting point - is to provide a *container*, since that's the abstraction we deal with: the "thing" that you think of is a linked **list**, not a **list node**. The data structure you learn of is, again, a linked **list**. And for a good reason: The node type is an implementation detail, so you'd need to come up with application-specific reasons for exposing the node type, and any argument made must stand up to the scrutiny when faced with iterators. Do you *really* need to expose those nodes, or is what you actually want just a convenient way to iterate over the items stored in the collection, perhaps split the list, etc? Node access is not necessary for any of it. It's all a solved problem, as you'll learn by reading the documentation of [`std::forward_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list).

You'd also want to consider allocator support. I'd not worry about the C++98 allocators, but the polymorphic allocators are (finally!) actually usable, so you'd want to implement those (c.f. `std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator` and the `std::pmr` namespace in general).

For full functionality, you'd pretty much need to add most of `std::forward_list`'s methods and constructors. So it's a bit of work, and there are lots of details to make it work well no matter the value type. And thus we come full circle: real containers that are meant to be useful without worrying about low-level details are lots of work, but they are a joy to use - and they look nothing like most textbook "teaching" code.

A linked list is often used when teaching data structures - true. Yet most C++ books used in teaching are woefully inadequate in demonstrating what a modern, fully functional data structure/container entails - they can't even get that right for something as "simple" as a singly linked list.

The gap between a C-like singly linked list - exactly what you started with in the question - and a singly linked list C++ container is on the order of a couple thousand lines of code and tests. That's what they don't usually teach, and that's where the most important bits really are: they are the difference between toy code, and production code.

Even without tests, a fully functional singly linked list container is ~500 lines without polymorphic allocator support, and probably at least double that with such support, and tests would double the code size several times - although if you were clever about it, you could reuse a lot of the tests used by various STL implementations :)

And, by the way: a decent implementation of a linked list in C won't force you to manually deal with nodes *either*. The list itself - the container - will be an abstract data type with a bunch of functions that provide the functionality, and with some abstraction for iterators as well (even though they'll be just pointers in some type-safe disguise). This is again the difference between teaching code and easy-to-use-correctly and hard-to-use-incorrectly production code. One example I can think of right now are the stretchy buffers, as implemented in [Bitwise ion](https://youtu.be/0woxSWjWsb8?t=759) project. This is a link to a video where those are implemented live, and they serve as a decent example of how abstractions work in C (and also how you definitely shouldn't be writing this in C++ - C and C++ are different languages!).